# VB Script for date extraction and formatting

Tags: date, vbscript, formatting, extract

I work on OCR. We extract text from invoices automatically. When the contents of the invoice are extracted they are stored in a text file, and then we write scripts to extract the data from the text file according to our requirements.

One requirement that has got me stuck is, I need to extract the date from a text file which is not written in any particular format. Its written as `12 08 2014` in a line. I need to extract this and print it out in the `dd/mm/yyyy` format. 
Also, the dates can be written in any format, for example 2nd December 2013, 12-12-2013, 12 Aug 2013 and so on. I need to read the date and extract it in the form of `dd/mm/yyyy`.

A little heads up for the problem.

1. There is no fixed location for the date. There are about 14000 invoices, most have a separate location of the date and separate format. I get the images and the scanned text file of the invoices, and i have to locate the date and try to format it.
2. The date is not after any fixed keyword that i could use. Like i mentioned in the first point, it can be after the word invoice number, or cost or any other work. SO the idea of searching it using keywords does not work as well.
3. This is the most stupid one, suppose I get the date 1/2/2011, how do I know whats the day and whats the month? The client has just entered a date, i have no way of finding out whats the day and the month. Is it even possible to find this out?

```
 ORDERED SHIPPED 

    01239751 28 08 14 03 09 14 E31192-00 1 
    CUST.NO. ItN1 R 0 R NO SALE MM 
    NOM CI WATT VOTRF NO nr CAMMANOF in-W.01M 
    ADDRESS HERE
    Te1:(123)123-1234/ Fax:(123)795-1234
    Facture / Invoice 
    OUTPS:R-103958989 CONE:MONS Taws> NET 60 DAYS 
    SOLD TO / VENDU A SHIPPED TO / EXPEDIE A
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far? SO works better if you show some effort. You are asking alot but showing no effort.

Comment: Hello Matt Thanks for the answer. Its not the code that i am looking for, i am looking for some ideas. I can extract my dates from the text files, but then problem i am facing is that there are  so many formats that i have to manually hard code it for every invoice. There are over 14000 of them. I am looking for some general ideas of extraction on the basis of the problems i have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You've already asked this.

You don't know and there is no way to know. We normally base it on the locale of the computer how dates are read. Yanks do m/d/y while the rest of the world do d/m/y. In the US windows functions assume the first and in the rest of the world the second.

As to years. Two digits are interpreted according to control panel settings. 29 and below is 2000 to 2029. 30 and above is 1930 - 1999.

Computers can not read the minds of people who write dates.

Comment: And you use regex to find it. "[0-3]?[0-9][ /-][0-1]?[0-9][ /-]2[0-9][0-9][0-9]" This one does 30 12 2014 with space, slash, or hypen as the delimiter.